# What is the documentation created by doxygen called

Tags: doxygen, code-documentation, design-documents

As I understood it "javadoc" is the name of the tool that generates html-documentation which also goes by the name javadoc. Atleast that is how I've been using the words..

But what is the generated output of the tool doxygen called? Doxygen-doc? doxy-doc? or maybe something else?

(Question in c++ context, if it matters)

Comment: we simply call it documentation, because we use only doxygen, but if you are using doxygen and javadoc, maybe you want to do it equivalent to "javadoc" javadoc and simply call "doxygen" doxygen, seems logical to me

Comment: We just call it "the doyxgen".

Comment: I usually go for "documentation", or if someone is curious enough, "the documentation generated by Doxygen". I think the style of comments in use are actually also called *javadoc* and *qtdoc* by Doxygen itself.

Answer (score 2):

Separate the tools from the output format.

Javadoc is a markup system. I think it is incorrect to call its html output (or any other output) "javadoc". The same way as you would not call a web page styled in Word "Word".

Similarly, Doxygen is also a markup system. It does not have its own documentation output type. Its 'types' are the output types it supports, that is: HTML, Latex, Man pages, RTF and more. See the [full list](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html).

You mention C++. Doxygen supports "C, Objective-C, C#, PHP, Java, Python, IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors), Fortran, VHDL, Tcl, and to some extent D.
See [Overview](http://www.doxygen.nl).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: "Design Documentation"

It's not a file format, it's a type of document that can be in any format.  Usually html if you used Doxygen to create it.